# Different hours in database, php

Tags: php, database, time, hour

So guys, I have a problem with time in my system

If I print this directly in my database(Mariadb using phpmyadmin) or directly in the server the time is correct..

```
mysql > SELECT now();
```

and when I print this directly in the file(.php)

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

but, if I print this...

```
echo $conn->query('SELECT NOW()')->fetchColumn(0);
```

the time shows with an hour more.

Can someone help me? What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, I am aware about date_default_timezone_set(), the time still shows wrong. @Luuk I edited my question

Comment: You have to do some testing/debugging, maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774010/time-difference-between-php-and-mysql

Comment: Thanks for helping me @Luuk , this solution seems a little trick to fixed, but I can't synchronized my PHP and MySQL timezones this way, because I am using multiple timezones.

Comment: make 1 testscript whit output from PHP-datetime  and the times you are getting from MySQL (+timezone). Also add the relevant values from settings to the testscript. Change settings, Evaluate testscript output, and start over... (until a solution is found...). .